# Huawei App Gallery - An app don't appear to some of users

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, appgallery

Unfortunately, some of the users could not access the app when they search about it and if they use the app link to reach it the app appears but the install button is disabled

Answer (score 0):

Please can you check what are devices the application is not available.

If the application unavailable for HMS devices, that means there is a Strong dependency on GMS (Google mobile services). So it will be available for download only GMS supporting devices. If you want to make it available on all devices, please integrate HMS services by implementing G+H approach so that it will be available on GMS and HMS devices.

Please follow the below link to integrate hms services with G+H approach:
https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topic/0201200435859940059

If only integration of HMS is needed, please refer to: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Library/android-sdk-download-0000001064112371